# Problemas con "tools:layout_editor_absoluteY/X" Android Studio: This view is not constrained

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

[image: Tengo problemas con las restricciones de las etiquetas de "tools:layout_editor_absoluteY/X"]

me muestra el mensaje:

> This view is not constrained, it only has design time positions, so it
>   will jump to (0,0) unless you add constraints

Tengo problemas con las restricciones de las etiquetas de "tools:layout_editor_absoluteY/X"

Answer (score 3):

Estas usando un [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout.html), y el mensaje en el caso de agregar un `ImageView` es:

> This view is not constrained, it only has design time positions, so it
>   will jump to (0,0) unless you add constraints

este mensaje no es un error, es solo un aviso (warning) acerca de que el `ImageView` se mostrara en la esquina superior izquierda (coordenadas 0,0), a menos que definas [restricciones](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/57515/95).

Debes definir constraints horizontales y verticales para posicionar tu vista en determinada zona de la pantalla, se realizar arrastrando los circulos definidos en los bordes de la prevista:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]