# Botones desordenados

Tags: android, android-layout

Mi problema me surge al hacer mi primera aplicación con botones y un cronometro (ejemplo que he visto en la red) en tiempo de diseño todo esta en su sitio pero al pasar al emulador todo se amontona en le lado superior izquierdo del teléfono.

Me podríais por favor decir cual es mi fallo pues por mas que leo no encuentro la forma de solucionar el problema

Adjunto el código:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.pedro.botones.Botones">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Boton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Entrada"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="61dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="812dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Boton2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Boton 2"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="525dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="812dp" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Hola @pedroperez. Bienvenido a [es.so]. Quizás una imagen ayudaría a entender lo que estás preguntando. ¿Qué emulador y con qué dimensiones estás usando?

Answer (score 1):

Prueba a introducir en tu layout xml diferentes tipo de contenedores ya pueden ser :

> - **LinearLayout:** Dispone los elementos en una fila o en una columna.
> - **TableLayout:** Distribuye los elementos de forma tabular.
> - **RelativeLayout:** Dispone los elementos en relación a otro o al padre.
> - **AbsoluteLayout:** Posiciona los elementos de forma absoluta.
> - **FrameLayout:** Permite el cambio dinámico de los elementos que contiene.

Tu código en un *RelativeLayout*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.pedro.botones.Botones">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Boton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Entrada"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="61dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="812dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Boton2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Boton 2"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="525dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="812dp" />

</RelativeLayout >
```

Te recomiendo que uses *RelativeLayout* o *AbsoluteLayout* (Este último esta un poco desactualizado, pero funciona muy bien)

En los LinearLayout tienes que tener en cuenta que existen dos tipos:

- Horizontal
- Vertical

Aqui te dejo la wiki de Android Developer

LINK : [Android Developer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html?hl=es-419)

Espero que te sirva !

Comment: Muchas Gracias funciona, pero una ultima pregunta para que sirve

Comment: Ya he aprendido como funciona "ConstraintLayout" uno es un poco burro pero no hay como leer. Gracias

Answer (score 1):

Estás utilizando un **ConstraintLayout** para tu contenedor principal, debes crear las restricciones pertinentes sobre cada botón para que se posicionen como tú quieras. Puedes hacer esto desde la vista **Design** de tu **xml layout** en la pantalla en azul que aparece a la derecha. Al hacer click sobre un elemento aparecerá en cada lado del mismo una opción para crear las restricciones de posicionamiento de una manera muy gráfica.

Si no conoces como funciona ConstraintLayout te recomiendo que pases por [aquí](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

Te recomiendo leer primeramente 
https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html

volvamos al inicio, elimina las posiciones, para que vuelvas a visualizar los botones en vista de diseño:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/Boton1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:text="Entrada"
    android:textSize="30sp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/Boton2"
    android:layout_width="147dp"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:text="Boton 2"
    android:textSize="30sp" />
```

Posteriormente puedes agregar un margen por ejemplo left (izquierdo) y top (arriba) para posicionar los botones, esto se realiza dando click y arrastrar alguno de los circulos verdes que se encuentra a la izquierda, derecha, arriba y abajo de la vista.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

obtendrías un layout similar a :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.pedro.botones.Botones">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Boton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Boton 1"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="119dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="49dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Boton2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:text="Boton 2"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="119dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="206dp" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Cuando ejecutes tu aplicación podras ver los botones de acuerdo a las posiciones que definiste en los elementos dentro del ConstraintLayout. Es importante leer la teoría y el uso de la herramienta.